# Android angle for rotation

Tags: canvas, bitmap

Still learning. Have read a lot about it but I'm stuck on some syntax now (I think).

My widget, Android, is supposed to rotate an imageView by an angle calculated in  relation to the day of the year.

My code is:

```
public int angle(Calendar calendarDate) {
    //Earth rotation;
    int day = calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    int angle;
    angle = (day / 365) * 360;
    return angle;
}

public void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    int angle;
    angle = angle(Calendar.getInstance());
```

...

```
tempCanvas.rotate(angle, pngOriginal.getWidth() / 2, pngOriginal.getHeight() / 2);
```

...

No error flashed when run, but it does not rotate - what am I doing wrong?
(I tried changing angle from `int` to `float`... it still does not work.)
Help will be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
public int angle(Calendar calendarDate) {
    int day = calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    int angle;
    angle = (day / 365) * 360;
    return angle;
}
```

to:

```
public static float angle(Calendar calendarDate) {

        float day;
        day = calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        float angle;
        angle = (day / 365) * 360;
        return angle;
    }
```

It works now.